# JavaFx FileChooser user defined filename

Tags: javafx, filechooser

I'm trying to use FileChooser, but I'm stuck with a trivial problem: after opening a FileChoser window, I can't seem to change the initial filename. This seems like a textbook task, but it got me.
Here is the code, which I'm trying to use:

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
fileChooser.setTitle("Save Image");
fileChooser.setInitialFileName("capture");
fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
    new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPG", "*.jpg")
);

File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this.primaryStage);
```

Comment: Did you try with a file name that matches the filter you provided (e.g. `capture.jpg`)?

Comment: Yes, the chooser dialog cut down the extension from the filename. Also have tried to set setInitialDirectory, had the same effect. Simply can't change the "capture" name at all. But saving the file with that name to any folder works.

Comment: OK, maybe I misunderstood. You're saying the file chooser displays the file name from the code (`capture`) but the user cannot change the name in the file chooser when it is displayed?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: It works fine for me. The `FileChooser` uses the native file chooser implementation, so this behavior is likely to be platform dependent. Which platform (OS and JDK version) are you running on?

Comment: win10 prof 1703, jdk 1.8_144, and the latest intelliJ (but I don't think that matters)

Comment: I don't have access to a Windows machine atm. Maybe someone who has a similar setup can see if they see the same thing. (It would help them to do so if you posted a [MCVE]: it wouldn't take a whole lot more code than you provided but it would be more convenient for someone to test if you did so.)

Comment: okay, so as it turns out (as I was making the example), the system-hook (a keyboard listener with JNI) module messed up the chooser dialog.This is a whole new problem... But thanks for the help, none the less!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found the culprit. The problem was with that I was using system-hook (https://github.com/kristian/system-hook), and this if the hook is initialized with `raw=true` value, the UI elements keyboard listeners stops working properly, reasons unknown. Using `raw=false` fixes this.